# JQuery element fade-in upon scroll - but at a certain point

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to make certain HTML sections fade in upon scrolling, but my current code has it set so they fade in as soon as the top of the element hits the page - causing them to prematurely appear and make the effect less dramatic. I'm trying to make it so the elements fade in halfway through the sections (or some sort of delay), so it is apparent that the effect is there.

Here is my JQuery code:

```
$(document).on("scroll", function () {
    var pageTop = $(document).scrollTop()
    var pageBottom = pageTop + $(window).height()
    var tags = $("section")


    for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; i++) {
        var tag = tags[i]
        
        if ($(tag).position().top < pageBottom) {
            $(tag).addClass("visible")
            } else {  $(tag).removeClass("visible")
            }
            }
});
```

CSS code is this:

```
section {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translate(0, 30px); transition: all 1s;
    }
    
section.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translate(0, 0); 
    }
```

HTML is something like

```
<section>
<img src="blablabla">
bla bla bla bblab alba
</section>
```

Comment: If they should show up half way through, then you should get the height of the section and use 1/2 of that as part of your equation.

Comment: Make your code runnable